# How to fetch created and updated status of JIRA ticket with Python API?

Tags: python, jira, atlassian-python-api

I'm trying to fetch the `created` and `updated` values from tickets in JIRA.

I'm able to pull issues using the following snippet (URL and credentials redacted):

```
from atlassian import Jira
import pandas as pd
import time
import glob


jira = Jira(
    url = "",
    username = "",
    password = "",
)

projects = ["PR1", "PR2", "PR3"]
FIELDS_OF_INTEREST = ["key", "fields.summary", "fields.status.name"]
timestamp = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
csv_folder = "./csvs/"
file_ending = ".csv"


for key in projects:
    output = csv_folder + key + timestamp + file_ending

    print(f"Currently processing: {key}")
    results = jira.jql(f"project = {key}", limit = 1000, fields=["issuetype", "status", "summary"])
    df = pd.json_normalize(results["issues"])
    df[FIELDS_OF_INTEREST].to_csv(output, index=False)
```

The objects returned, even without the `FIELDS_OF_INTEREST` applied, does not contain the timestamps. To get the timestamps I need to pass in `expand=changelog`. But when I do that I no longer get the same structure I'm looking for. The `created` and `updated` information is available then though.

The following snippet is the one I'm currently using trying to extract the timestamp (URL and credentials redacted):

```
from atlassian import Jira
import pandas as pd
import time
import glob


jira = Jira(
    url = "",
    username = "",
    password = "",
)


projects = ["PR1", "PR2", "PR3"]

for key in projects:
    issues = jira.jql(f"project=  {key}", limit = 5, expand='changelog')
    df = pd.json_normalize(issues)
    df.to_csv("changelog.csv", index=False)
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. I would love to be able to know how to pull these data points.

I'm unable to find any examples in: https://github.com/atlassian-api/atlassian-python-api/tree/master/examples/jira or in the documentation.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do more inspection to get the actual dates and timestamps you are looking for

The example most relevant is probably from the [ReportGenerator](https://github.com/atlassian-api/atlassian-python-api/blob/d4195a8963c69a248fc865177e141bdcfd59eb21/examples/jira/jira_jql_fetcher_as_weekly_report.py#L19).

In the JQL, `created` is added to the `fields` list, and the changelog is expanded. See [this section](https://github.com/atlassian-api/atlassian-python-api/blob/d4195a8963c69a248fc865177e141bdcfd59eb21/examples/jira/jira_jql_fetcher_as_weekly_report.py#L36-L39).

After that, in the [main execution](https://github.com/atlassian-api/atlassian-python-api/blob/d4195a8963c69a248fc865177e141bdcfd59eb21/examples/jira/jira_jql_fetcher_as_weekly_report.py#L94-L95), the histories are inspected for the changes/and their dates, [and emitted](https://github.com/atlassian-api/atlassian-python-api/blob/d4195a8963c69a248fc865177e141bdcfd59eb21/examples/jira/jira_jql_fetcher_as_weekly_report.py#L59-L67).